# Bootstrap: Adding button over a picture

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Currently, I have the following code to display my pictures.

```
<section id="gallery" class="row no-gutters">
  {% for image in images %}
    <a class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3" href="{{ image.image.url }}">
      <img src="{% get_image image.image.url 'event_gallery_medium' %}" class="w-100">
    </a>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
```

I now try to add a button in the bottom right corner, where people can also click on it. The button should open `{{ image.image.url }}`.

I created the button:

```
<span class="d-md-none btn btn-sm btn-white">
  <span class="fas fa-expand mr-2"></span>
  View Photos
</span>
```

But I still struggle how to place it "over" the picture so it's in the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit, I hope you like it.

```css
.button_class {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section id="gallery" class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 position-relative" href="google.com">
      <a href="https://google.com" class="d-block"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="w-100"></a>
      <a href="https://google.com" class="btn btn-info button_class">Button</a>
    </div>
</section>
```